# I need a little help with the grammar of "despite"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Hey guys I was originally trying to imply that among all the European languages, English resembles Chinese the most closely for they both have a relatively clear set of grammar rules, but the two languages still have lots of differents in between, and I made up a sentence, goes like

> " Despite that with its set of simple grammar rules, English, among
>   all the European languages, resembles Chinese the most closely, many
>   differences still remain in between."

But im feeling something is not right here, and here are my questions,

> 1. is it okay to say "A resemble B the most"? or "A resemble B the most
>      closely" exclusively?
> 2. Is this sentence wrong in grammer?
> 3. How could i improve this sentence, so that it looks more authentic?

Comment: There are obvious grammatical errors. However another problem is that you are trying to say too much in one sentence. Try: "English, with its simpler grammar rules among European languages, resembles Chinese most closely. Despite this, many differences remain between them."

Comment: 'English, in having simpler grammar than other European languages, resembles Chinese the most closely. But many differences still remain.' // 'Simpler', if correct here, must obviously be a relative term. Have a look at a few posts here. // 'Despite that ... English resembles ...' is incorrect: it would have to be  'Despite the fact that ... English resembles ...'.

Comment: thanks for answering, ws2 and edwin,and i'm getting a better grip on this now :D